# Change of "standings" in a table and converting consecutive rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is source table emp , 
look into the table and required output below:

EMP:
HERE IS THE SOURCE TABLE:

```
EMPID    ENAME    STANDING    DATE
101       ABC      ACTIVE      10-06-91
101       ABC      INACTIVE   01-07-2002
102       EFG      INACTIVE   02-09-2009
102       EFG      ACTIVE     01-10-2011
102       EFG      INACTIVE   07-10-2017
103       XYZ      ACTIVE     08-07-2010
103       XYZ      ACTIVE     08-07-2010
103       XYZ      INACTIVE   09-10-2011
```

OUTPUT:

```
EMPID     ENAME    BEFORESTANDING        CURRENTSTANDING    DATE
101       ABC       ACTVE                INACTIVE           01-07-2002
102       EFG       INACTIVE             ACTIVE             01-10-2011
102       EFG       ACTIVE               INACTIVE           07-10-2017
103       XYZ       ACTIVE               INACTIVE           09-10-2011
```

Transformation rule logic is if the empid is same and it has got change of STANDING   from active to inactive,
the output will be in a single row and date coulmn will be from latest record.

if the table has got three standings of inactive to active and active to inactive we will maintain 2 rows in the output[(n-1) for output]
with the change of standings

if the table has got same standings in the consequitive rows then will skip the first one and only consider the change of standings.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? In 2012 (and newer) you can easily do this using [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAG` is the best approach if you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+`, if in case you are using older version here is some approaches to do it

**`Cross Apply` :**

```
SELECT a.EMPID,
       a.ENAME,
       BEFORESTANDING= cs.STANDING,
       CURRENTSTANDING= a.STANDING,
       a.date
FROM   Yourtable a
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   Yourtable b
                    WHERE  a.EMPID = b.EMPID
                           AND a.DATE > b.DATE
                    ORDER  BY b.Date DESC) AS cs
```

**`SELF JOIN` :**

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                Rn = Row_number()OVER(partition BY EMPID ORDER BY DATE)
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT a.EMPID,
       a.ENAME,
       BEFORESTANDING = b.STANDING,
       CURRENTSTANDING= a.STANDING,
       a.DATE
FROM   CTE a
       JOIN CTE b
         ON a.EMPID = b.EMPID
            AND a.Rn = b.Rn + 1
WHERE  a.STANDING <> b.STANDING
ORDER  BY a.EMPID,
          a.DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can easily do this using [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function

```
WITH CTE_Source AS
(
    SELECT *
    , LAG(STANDING) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, Ename ORDER BY DATE) AS BEFORE_STANDING
    FROM Emp
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_Source
WHERE BEFORE_STANDING <> STANDING
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e56d6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, the following should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    EMPID INT NOT NULL,
    ENAME CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    STANDING VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [DATE] DATE NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (EMPID, ENAME, STANDING, [DATE]) VALUES
    ('101', 'ABC', 'ACTIVE  ', '10-06-1991'),
    ('101', 'ABC', 'INACTIVE', '01-07-2002'),
    ('102', 'EFG', 'INACTIVE', '02-09-2009'),
    ('102', 'EFG', 'ACTIVE  ', '01-10-2011'),
    ('102', 'EFG', 'INACTIVE', '07-10-2017'),
    ('103', 'XYZ', 'ACTIVE  ', '08-07-2010'),
    ('103', 'XYZ', 'ACTIVE  ', '08-07-2010'),
    ('103', 'XYZ', 'INACTIVE', '09-10-2011');

--=============================================

WITH 
    cte_AddBeforeStanding AS (
        SELECT 
            td.EMPID,
            td.ENAME,
            BEFORESTANDING = LAG(td.STANDING, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.EMPID ORDER BY td.DATE),
            CURRENTSTANDING = td.STANDING,
            td.DATE
        FROM 
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    bs.EMPID,
    bs.ENAME,
    bs.BEFORESTANDING,
    bs.CURRENTSTANDING,
    bs.DATE
FROM 
    cte_AddBeforeStanding bs
WHERE 
    bs.BEFORESTANDING <> bs.CURRENTSTANDING;
```

HTH, Jason

Comment: Will not produce the expected result

Comment: Updated the final WHERE clause.

Comment: Now `bs.BEFORESTANDING IS NOT NULL` condition is redundant ;). If you remove it then it is a duplicate of [Nenad Zivkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511869/3349551) answer ;)

Comment: It wasn't negatively impacting anything but cleaner code is better code, so it's gone now.